# jQuery DataTables "nCell is undefined" on Compex Table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the following scripts and the following code and keep getting the error

```
nCell is undefined
```

on line 669 which is

```
nCell.className += ' '+oCol.sClass;
```

Can anyone shed any light on this please? I couldn't get jsFiddle to work as needed unfortunately

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/3.0.2/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" id="qipp">
                    <thead>

                        <tr>
                            <th class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="Evaluation & Testing Criteria">Evaluation</a></th>
                            <th class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="Component Projects">Components</a></th>
                            <th class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="Gross Savings 13/24 £'000">Gross</a></th>
                            <th colspan="3" class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="Risk Share - Gross Savings">Risk Share</a></th>
                            <th colspan="2" class="success">YTD</th>
                            <th class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="Total Forecast Delivery In Year">Total</a></th>
                            <th class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="Revised Forecast Delivery In Year (CCG adjusted)">Revised</a></th>
                            <th class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="Variance from Plan & FOT">Variance</a></th>
                            <th class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="Variance from Plan & Adjusted FOT">Variance Adj.</a></th>
                            <th colspan="3" class="success">RAG</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="active"></th>
                            <th class="active"></th>
                            <th class="active"></th>
                            <th class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="GHTF Risk £'000">GHTF</a></th>
                            <th class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-content="CCG Risk £'000">CCG</a></th>
                            <th class="active"></th>
                            <th class="success">Activity</th>
                            <th class="success">Cost</th>
                            <th class="active"></th>
                            <th class="active"></th>
                            <th class="active"></th>
                            <th class="active"></th>
                            <th class="success">Project</th>
                            <th class="success">Savings</th>
                            <th class="success">Recurrent / Trend</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="warning" colspan="15">{THEME 1}</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="5" class="text-center"><a data-content="<strong>Work Programme:</strong> {} <br/> <strong>GCCG Project Lead:</strong> {} <br/> <strong>Finance Lead:</strong> {} <br/> <strong>Information Lead:</strong> {}" title="Information">{NAME}</a></td>
                            <td rowspan="5" class="text-center">0</td>
                            <td rowspan="5" class="text-center">0</td>
                            <td rowspan="5" class="text-center">-</td>
                            <td rowspan="5" class="text-center">-</td>

                            <td>Actual</td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1">0</a></td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1">0</a></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Plan</td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1">0</a></td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1">0</a></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Variance</td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1">0</a></td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1">0</a></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Row #4</td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1">0</a></td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1">0</a></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Row #5</td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1">0</a></td>
                            <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1">0</a></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                            <td>G</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

Comment: We need to see exactly where nCell is defined. Probably is a wrong selector...

Comment: It's on line 669 of the JS plugin. if ( bClass )
      {
       nCell.className += ' '+oCol.sClass;
      }

Comment: I can see you are changing the value of the attribute "className", but by then "nCell" must exist already. Where does it come from?

Comment: I've no idea - this is literally all I have in the page. It works if I get rid of the various rowspans and colspans which is obviously not something I want to do

Comment: Are you initialising the table properly? Check the creator's examples, they are self-explanative. Unfortunately, without more information we cannot help you much.

Comment: $(function () {
                $('#qipp').dataTable();
            });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38800/discussion-between-janusz-jasinski-and-opalenzuela)

Comment: jQuery datatables does **NOT** support `colspan` nor `rowspan`. This is your problem.

Comment: See [DataTables and colspan](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14/datatables-and-colspan/p1). Also, multiple `<thead>`'s is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

DataTables does not support colspan or rowspan in the TBODY....

Comment: Good catch; any chance you can link to a source for this too?

Comment: I see this on official DataTable forum like this : http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/42997

Answer (score 1):

Also check correct tr and td number. 
Have to be same number is thead and tbody.